# Why can't I get regular data out of my PostgresDB with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

When I output the data from `Role.where(user_id: [current_user.id])` I get:

```
#<Role::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f8afc3d75c8>
```

I've tried to manipulate this to get the actual data out and nothing is working. Very confused as I know I've gotten normal data in the past...

For example, in my data base there is a column "user_id" and a column "admin". I have records saved but am not able to pull the values from the user row...

Comment: Have you tried this :  Role.find_by("user_id = ?", current_user.id)

Comment: Yes - Returns the same thing... So I still can't get the true values I need...

Answer (score 0):

Because `.where` returns an object that can be queried further. If you want an actual record do `.first` or `.take(n)` where n is a number after the `.where`.

Comment: How do I query it further? I tried the "r.user_id" and it didn't work... where I set r equal to "Role.where(user_id: [current_user.id])"

Comment: Querying it further means that you can apply more calls to `.where`, `.joins` and the whole database API provided by `ActiveRecord`.

You can't call `user_id` on the result of a `.where` because that call represents a _result set_ not a single result. It's analog to having an array of values, not a single value.

As I said, you need to call `.first` on it to pick the first result out of your result set.

`r = Role.where(user_id: [current_user.id]).first`
`r.user_id      # this will work`